# A Question About Code For Searching For Words Without Certain Letters In A Text File

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm currently working through a introductory python book called "Think Python". In one of the exercises, I'm supposed to write a program that takes a string of characters, and counts how many words in file called "words.txt" (http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/code/words.txt) do not have letters from that string of characters.

My code is here:

```
fin = open('words.txt')

def avoids(word,forbidden):
    avoided=True 
    for i in forbidden:
        if i in word: 
            avoided=False
            break #break out of for loop
    if avoided==True:
        return avoided 

def number_avoids(forbidden):
    """Finds number of words excluded by character"""
    avoided=0
    for line in fin:
        if avoids(line,forbidden):
            avoided+=1
    return avoided

print(number_avoids("a"))
print(number_avoids("a"))
```

What I'm confused about though, is why I got two different answers for the same code. For the first `print(number_avoids("a"))`, the result was 57196. For the second one, the program printed out 0. Could someone explain to me why the same code will give out two different answers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

When you open a file, there's a `cursor` which points to the current position in file. At first function call, this cursor is at the starting of the file. So, it reads all the contents and your program works well.

But, when you call the function second time, the `cursor` is at the **End of File**. So, there are no more characters to read. You can verify it by adding a `print(line)` statement inside your loop of `number_avoids` function.

## Solution

There's a builtin function to move the file cursor. You can use it to move your cursor to initial position:

```py
...
print(number_avoids("a"))
fin.seek(0)
print(number_avoids("a"))
```

It will move your cursor to the start of file. So, all of the file contents will be read and evaluated again.

**Note**: I have tried to make this answer as basic as I can so that it can be understood by anyone without the knowledge of file handling. Feel free to ask for any clarifications in comments.

Comment: This is a good start, but you may want to consider opening the file in the function, to avoid globals and use proper response management with `with`